# MCR permission problems with multinode hadoop setup on linux

Tags: linux, matlab, hadoop, permissions

I am trying to run a program called Phenoripper(image analysis software) that utilizes MCR inside of a Hadoop multi-node setup (version 1.1.2) on Ubuntu (13.04). The hadoop setup works perfectly with generic python/java mapreduce jobs; however, when I try to use phenoripper in the setup I get this error:

boost::filesystem::create_directory:permission denied

I have asked the devs of Phenoripper about this and they have assured me that their program is not creating or writing to temporary directories and since it works on a single computer perfectly I believe that MCR is responsible for this error. If I understand correctly, it is trying to create a temporary directory somewhere where it doesn't have permission, likely on one of the slave nodes. Does anyone have any idea where this directory might be located or how to find it? If I can find this directory, my solution would be to permanently create it with appropriate permissions. Does this sound like a viable solution? Any ideas as to what on earth is going on/how to fix it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed...the most recent version of MCR as of this post has a major error in which some process looks for a /homes/ directory with the .matlab directory in it...Some programmer must've just put an extra s in there equaling days of pain. Creating that directory under 777 permissions and putting the .matlab folder in it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have very little experience with MCR but here is my attempt to help guide you in the right direction from a Hadoop tmp directory perspective.

It's conceivable that the permissions when running Phenoripper are different when they encounter the creation of tmp directories in Hadoop. If you want to understand where the temp dirs are in Hadoop take a look at your hadoop-site or core-site and find:

```
<property>
<name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
<value>/tmp/hadoop-${user.name}</value>
</property>
```

This is the basis for all the tmp directories found in hadoop. Then take a look at the following configuration parameters in hdfs-site:

```
dfs.datanode.data.dir(new name) or dfs.data.dir (old name)
```

This contains the data blocks your job writes.

The user.name hadoop uses to create these permissions is the same user you encounter when you ask [whoami](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hdfs_permissions_guide.html)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but that wasn't the problem...it was actually an error made by the MCR programmers